# Looking for a google-analytics-style map creating app or api

Tags: google-maps, maps, ip-geolocation, statistics

I am looking for a google-analytics-style map creating app or api based on visitor IP addresses, any suggestions?

thanks,

nicoperez

Answer (score 8):

Did you take a look at the [Google Visualization API](http://code.google.com/apis/visualization/)? Specifically, the [intensity map](http://code.google.com/apis/visualization/documentation/gallery/intensitymap.html) and the [geomap](http://code.google.com/apis/visualization/documentation/gallery/geomap.html).

Comment: Haven't looked at the Visualization stuff before.  Looks very nice.

Answer (score 1):

I know there are a few of these services available. Try a google search for 'ip visitor geolocation' and similar combinations.

One that looks interesting is [hostip.info](http://www.hostip.info/) as they have a community-maintained IP geolocation database that you can download in full if you wish to roll your own map.

They also provide a [service](http://geostats.hostip.info/) where you can upload your logs to generate a little map image if you don't want to do the work yourself.

Answer (score 0):

We recently added a feature for this to our [EmbeddedAnalytics](http://www.embeddedanalytics.com) service.  It is all based on your Google Analytics data and utilizes Google's Exp API for the data.